# Laravel get column length and turn into spaces

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, eloquent

I dont know if this is possible but what I want is to convert the remaining characters of the column into spaces. For example

I have a column name `first_name` and it has a length of `10`

Then I have a data of `Paul`, since the name has 4 characters in it, then the remaining spaces are 6. Its like `db_length - db_data = spaces`. The data or the output would be

```
Name: Paul------
```

I emphasized the spaces as dash `-`

I asked this question since I am writing a text file and there is a space after each data and that is the requirements. If I can only do a fixed spaces then I wouldn't ask this question. If you have any idea how to do it please share. Thanks!

Comment: "I asked this question since I am writing a text file and there is a space after each data and that is the requirements" What does that mean exactly?

Comment: Take a look at PHP's `str_pad` method: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php. You can "pad" strings that are too short with any kind of "padding string" (like `-`). You'd need to determine which value is the longest, and pad anything shorter to match (assuming that's your issue; your question is a little unclear)

Comment: `echo str_pad($first_name, 10);` [Read the manual](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-pad.php) _Occasionally_

Comment: @geertjanknapen. In a text file after the data is being printed. there is another data beside it. there would be spaces right so you can read the text. so the exact spaces are the remaining column length of the data.

Comment: I dont know why the question is closed. The reference question is different

Comment: Is that one better?